# Arduino to RPi using Bluetooth?

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, arduino, communication

I'm working on a project that the goal is to send data from an Arduino (a Flora, specifically, reading sensor information) directly to a Raspberry Pi using BLE. I'm following [this guide](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/bluefruit-le-python-library.pdf), and on running the uart_service.py program, I get up to "Discovering Services" before the terminal fills up with a ton of messages, and I don't even know where to start to figure this out. The output of the program is [here](https://pastebin.com/uvKVA7zL).

So my question is how do I go about troubleshooting this or, failing that, is there another alternative that someone can point me in the right direction of to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue using Bluez version higher than 5.37.
 From [this link](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=97475) suggests you need Jessie from 2016-05-27 release and then used bluez 5.37.

[Bluez 5.37](https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/installation) installation guide

Comment: Didn't exactly follow this, but you did give me the idea to use the exact version of Bluez that was included in the tutorial (5.33) and it worked! Thanks for the idea.

Comment: glad you got it working